# If conditions is not working in javascript injection

Tags: javascript, performance

I am working on a project where i want to change the value of the desired text boxes in the web page.
I am using `javascript` injection to the web browser to paste the values of the text fields.

In the code below, I have taken a `activeElement` in the document and compare it with other element in the element List. and want to paste another string in the next text field. But in the below code the `if----elseif---` condition is not working as desired.

```
var editcount = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var fcElement = document.activeElement;
var cpt = 0;
var bFlag = false;
for (cpt = 0; cpt < editcount.length; cpt++) {
    if (editcount[cpt].id == fcElement.id && !bFlag) {
        fcElement.value = "Username";
        bFlag = true;
    }
    else if((editcount[cpt].type == "password"||editcount[cpt].type == "text" || editcount[cpt].type == "email") && bFlag === true) {
        editcount[cpt].value = "Password";
        break;
    }
}
```

Here, the *password* is also copied on the *same text field.*

can anyone tell me whats wrong with the script ?

Comment: add more parenthesis `if ((editcount[cpt].id == fcElement.id) && !(bFlag)) {...`

Comment: @adeneo Why are you suggesting that? What could be the problem here?

Comment: When are you running this? If it's on pageload, why would the activeElement be anything other than "window"

Comment: after selecting a textbox in the web page, i am injecting the script from  my application

Comment: what is `fcElement` value?

Comment: @Grundy 'fcElement' is a currently focused element in the web page which is returned by 'document.activeElement'

Comment: i mean you check it value in runtime?

Comment: how you use js injection to browser?

Comment: @Grundy  my code is over writing the text box values. but as per the program running flow it should not happen. but it is happening

Comment: how you call this script? can you provide your sample html?

Comment: By using 'execScript' of  'IHTMLWindow' in MFC

Comment: can you provide `fcElement` value at runtime when you try it?

Comment: @Grundy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20704989/java-script-injection-not-working-as-desired-in-mfc-application

Comment: @Grundy the `fcElement`is value of selected text box in the web page

Comment: as javascript its work, so possible problem with your injection

Comment: @Grundy I have tried same script on [jsfiddle.com] it is showing problem as i explained it is over writing the value of **username** with **password**.

Comment: try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9gFj/579/)

Comment: @Grundy yeah, it is working fine for your example but how can i add a `mouseup` event on current web page elements as my application is unknown of IDs of the elements. Can you please tell me if you have any idea about that. I am new in `Javascript`.

Comment: i think you need wrap it in function, and then call it

Comment: MY problem has been solved thank you @Grundy and all. the problem was with the code where I am comparing ids of elements. I changed that code for comparison with name of elements.

Comment: @AnkitB so how you solve it? :-)

Comment: I have changed ` if (editcount[cpt].id == fcElement.id)` to ` if (editcount[cpt].name == fcElement.name)` and problem have been solved. thank you @grundy

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help. 
I was having problem with my code.
I was comparing the ids of the two elements.
`if (editcount[cpt].id == fcElement.id && !bFlag)`

and this was not working for some web pages but now I got the solution for it.

I have changed the condition of comparision of elements as below.
`if (editcount[cpt].name == fcElement.name && !bFlag)`

and My problem has solved.
I am posting my working code here...
`

```
var editcount = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
var fcElement = document.activeElement;
var cpt = 0;
var bFlag = false;
console.log(fcElement);
for (cpt = 0; cpt < editcount.length; cpt++) {
    console.log(editcount[cpt]);
    if (editcount[cpt].name == fcElement.name) {
        fcElement.value = "Username";
        bFlag = true;
    } else if ((editcount[cpt].type == "password" || editcount[cpt].type == "text" || editcount[cpt].type == "email") && bFlag === true) {
        editcount[cpt].value = "Password";
        break;
    }
}`
```

Thank you for your cooperation.
Merry Christmas.